# ngTagsInput not populating from angular $http

Tags: angularjs, ng-tags-input

Im a complete angularjs newbie. So hopefully I am somewhat on track.

I have a datacontext configured like

```
(function () {
'use strict';

var serviceId = 'datacontext';
angular.module('app').factory(serviceId, ['common', '$http', datacontext]);

function datacontext(common, $http) {
    var $q = common.$q;

    var service = {
        getCustomerGroups: getCustomerGroups
    };

    return service;


    function getCustomerGroups() {
        var groups = [];

        $http({ method: 'GET', url: '/api/getgroups' }).
                success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        console.log(status);
                        console.log(headers);
                        console.log(data);
                        groups = data;
                        return $q.when(groups);

            }).
error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(data);
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
});
          return $q.when(groups);
    }
}
})();
```

Within my view I am using ngTagsInput

```
                        <tags-input ng-model="groups"
                                display-property="GroupName"
                                placeholder="Add Customer Group"
                                enableeditinglasttag="false"
                                class="ui-tags-input"
                                replace-spaces-with-dashes="false">
                    </tags-input>
```

And finally my controller

```
(function () {
'use strict';
var controllerId = 'customers';
angular.module('app').controller(controllerId, ['common','$scope','$http','datacontext', customers]);

function customers(common,$scope,$http,datacontext) {

    var vm = this;
    vm.title = 'Customers';
    $scope.groups = [];


    function getGroups() {
        return datacontext.getCustomerGroups().then(function (data) {
            return $scope.groups = data;
        });
    }

    activate();

    function activate() {
        var promises = [getGroups()];
        common.activateController(promises, controllerId)
            .then(function() {

            }
       );
    }



}
})();
```

I am not getting any errors and I can see the correct data is returned in the success method of $http. However the tag is not populated. Is it because the tag is calling the datasource before the $http has completed?

Comment: Is the first code snippet your actual code? It doesn't seem to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how $q.when works, but it returns promise but does not resolve it. You should us the defer api.

So at start set

```
var defer = common.$q.defer();
```

and later in success do defer.resolve.

```
 success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        console.log(status);
                        console.log(headers);
                        console.log(data);
                        groups = data;
                        defer.resolve(data);
```

and see if it works.

Comment: Hi Chandermani, Ive added the defer var into my function getCustomerGroups() {} Should I still be trying to return the array like    return $q.when(groups);

Comment: NO. That is a callback function not your getCustomerGroups function.